# How to modify(invalidate) LayerDrawable children inset without recreating it?

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable

I'm working on View that dynamically changes inset of drawables in its background.

My working solution is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    bg = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.combined).mutate();
    bg.setLayerInset(middlePartIndex,new Random().nextInt()%50,0,30,0);
    setBackground(bg);
}
```

I can't get it working without recreation of background drawable in each change.  I've tried to call `invalidate`, `invalidateDrawable(bg)` on View, `invalidateSelf` on Drawable. Nothing works.